Subadditivity in Trace of sum of three squared matrices
Let $A,B$ and $C$ be three PSD matrices. How can one prove or give a counter-example for the following statement?
$$
\text{tr}(A^2+(B+C)^2)^{1/2}\leq \text{tr}(A^2+B^2)^{1/2}+\text{tr}(A^2+C^2)^{1/2}.
$$
I know some simple inequality, such as $\text{tr}(A+B)^{1/2}\leq \text{tr}A^{1/2}+\text{tr}B^{1/2}$. But this doesn't work. Can somebody help me？ I'd appreciate it.
Remark: Thanks for the suggestion from @user1551, the notation $\text{tr}(\cdots)^{1/2}$ stands for $\text{tr}\sqrt{(\cdots)}$. Numerical experiments also support this inequality, code is shown in follow.
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm
import random
import time

def generate_spd_matrix(n):
    flag=True
    while flag==True:
        A = np.random.randn(n, n)
        rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)
        if rank == n:
            flag = False
    symmetric_positive_definite_matrix = np.dot(A.T, A)
    return symmetric_positive_definite_matrix

begin = time.time()
count = 0
for i in range(10000):
    order = int(np.random.uniform(10, 100))
    A = generate_spd_matrix(order)
    B = generate_spd_matrix(order)
    C = generate_spd_matrix(order)
    temp1 = np.trace(sqrtm(np.dot(A, A) + np.dot(B+C, B+C)))
    temp2 = np.trace(sqrtm(np.dot(A, A) + np.dot(B, B)))
    temp3 = np.trace(sqrtm(np.dot(A, A) + np.dot(C, C)))
    
    if temp1 <= temp2 + temp3:
        count += 1

end = time.time()-begin
print('Count', count, 'Time', end)


@user1551 Hello, thank you for your suggestion. I have checked it by computer simulation. The results support the above inequality.

It probably doesn’t work but have you tried some Cauchy-Schwartz with the canonical matricial scalar product?

@julio_es_sui_glace Hello, I haven't tried it the way you say. So far, I consider that (a). when A=0, the equal holds, and (b). when A = I, the inequality holds (By Weyl theorem on $B+C$). I think we just need to prove (c). this is true if A is diagonal. For other cases of A, orthogonal diagonalization can be used to reduce it into case (c)

Note that matrix square root is operator monotone on the set of all positive semidefinite matrices. Using Schatten $1$-norm, we get
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}\sqrt{A^2+(B+C)^2}
&\le\operatorname{tr}\sqrt{(A+A)^2+(B+C)^2}\\
&=\left\|\pmatrix{A+A\\ B+C}\right\|\\
&\le\left\|\pmatrix{A\\ B}\right\|+\left\|\pmatrix{A\\ C}\right\|\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\sqrt{A^2+B^2}+\operatorname{tr}\sqrt{A^2+C^2}.\\
\end{align*}

Thank you very much. That is excellent proof!
